# How do I check for nothing in the input buffer/stream in C?

Tags: c, input, stream, buffer, flush

I have searched for many solutions on this but none have met my needs.

I need to:

1. Read two integers separated by spaces using `scanf()`.
2. If there is only one integer entered, I need to check for that and clear the buffer.
3. If there are more than 2 integers entered, I need to check for that and clear the buffer.

So far I have been using `getchar()` to achieve the checking and clearing. The problem is that if there is nothing in the buffer, `getchar()` waits for a character.

**How do I check to see if there is nothing in the input buffer/stream?** This way if there is nothing, I don't have to clear the buffer with `getchar()`.

Comment: You can check the end-of-line character. If the last call to `getchar();` returns `'\n'`, you've reached the end of the line.

Comment: @CoolGuy I have already thought of that. It doesn't work for my purposes. I need a different way to check.

Comment: It should. Show your code along with some sample inputs and outputs. I don't think there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this with standard C - check for characters in the `stdin` buffer and *immediately* return if nothing exist.

Yet I do not think that is really needed here anyways.  Just read a line using `fgets()`, waiting for the user to type 0 or more characters and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> which will put a `'\n'` in `stdin`. `fgets()` will then return.

Use `"%n"` to record where scanning was at that point and insure proper space delimiter and detect extra garbage.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential \n

int n1, n2;
int cnt = sscanf(buf, "%d%n%d%n", &d1, &n1, &d2, &n2);

if (buf[0] == '\0') Handle_NothingWasEntered();
else if (cnt == 1 && buf[n1] == '\0') Handle_OneWasEntered(d1);
else if (cnt == 2 && buf[n1] == ' ' && buf[n2] == '\0') Handle_TwoWereEntered(d1, d2);
else Handle_BadInput(buf);
}
```